# Автоматизация запуска main метода

Tags: java

Вопрос следующий. Есть некое приложение, в методе main оно выполняет действия, по ходу работы всю информацию логгирует и записывает в файл. Для получения более менее наглядной картины этот сценарий надо выполнить >200 раз. Каждый раз запускать приложение вручную как то не очень хочется)
Какие вы могли бы посоветовать инструменты для того, чтобы этот процесс как то автоматизировать? Понимаю, что вопрос может быть звучит глупо, но впервые сталкиваюсь с подобной проблемой. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Ни разу про циклы не слышали? ``for``, ``while``, ``do {...} while``

Answer (score 6):

можно в main в аргументах передать количество запусков и в цикле выполнить то, что делаете.

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
   int loop = 1;
   if (args.length > 0) { 
       loop = Integer.parseInt(args[0])
   }

   while (--loop > 0) {
     //do something 
   }
```

программу запускаете из интерпретатора командной строки.  Тогда вы зацикливаете количество запусков выполнения вашей команды. 
Пример для Linux-а

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..200}
do
   java -jar MyProgram.jar
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Если вы являетесь автором этого приложения, то выносите из метода main всю логику, а в main вставьте цикл с вызовом логики 200 раз.

Если приложение чужое и нет доступа к исходникам, то организуйте цикл вызова 200 раз средствами оболочки OS, например, bash для Linux, CMD/BAT/PowerShell для Windows.